# Scraping through pages in multi-paged results of Genbank

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, genbank

Example: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=trocholejeunea
In which there're 79 items in 4 pages, however, when I went through pages by clicking "Previous" or "Next", the address turns into 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/
It doesn't work by adding "&page=2" at the end, and no href or javascript can be seen in the source code:

```
<a name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page" title="Next page of results" class="active page_link next" id="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page" accesskey="k" href="#" sid="3" page="2">Next &gt;</a>
```

I wonder how does this realized, and how to crawl it by java? Thanks!